# Disable table cell spacing when zooming on iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

Is there way to disable this table cell spacing when zooming on iOS Safari?

Screenshot:

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2d2hml0&s=6]

It occurs in iOS5 simulator and iPad 1 with iOS5 to me.

Testcase: http://dabblet.com/gist/2761189

Answer (score 0):

I fear it's some iOS bug with drawing. Because if you zoom to maximum level, there's no line.